# How to print specific numbers from a for loop using Kotlin

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

So I am fairly new to Kotlin and I need to generate specific numbers from a for loop of 1 to 13.

For the first output I need only odd numbers

For the second output I need numbers 2, 5, 8, 11, 14, 19 and 20 from a for loop of 0 to 20

For starters I can print an entire list using:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    for (i in 1..13){

        println(i)
    }


}
}
```

But that's it. What do I need to print the other required outputs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you know how to write a `for` loop that prints every number, the question becomes how to identify a number that you "should" print from a number that you should not.

Your first sequence is all odd numbers, so @DipankarBaghel's answer covers that. Your second sequence seems to be all numbers for which the remainder when dividing by 3 is 2. (Except 19; did you mean 17 for that one?)

You can use the same operator in this case, but instead of checking for `0` (or for `!= 0`) you can check that the remainder is `2`:

```
for (i in 0..20) {
    if (i % 3 == 2) {
        println(i)
    }
}
```

The key concept here is that of `%`, the *remainder operator* (sometimes called the *modulo operator*). The result of `x % y` will be the remainder when `x` is divided by `y`. Odd numbers have a remainder of `1` when divided by `2`, so `i % 2 == 1` will be true only for (positive) odd numbers.

Comment: Yes I mean't 17 for that one, or atleast that's the number I was instructed to generate. Other than that thanks!

Comment: Actually wait it is supposed to be 17, not 19. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 0):

To check even you need to do `i%2==0` and for odd just check `i%2!=0`.

```
for (i in 1..13){

        if(i%2!=0){
            println("odd number "+i);
        }
        if(i%2==0){
            println("even number "+i);
        }
    }
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: @Preston  If the answer helps you request you to mark the answer as accepted so that it will helps others too. thanks

Answer (score 0):

To generate **Odd** numbers:

```
for (i in 1..13) {
    if(i % 2 == 1 ){
        println(i + ", ");
    }
}
```

To Generate **2, 5, 8, 11, 14, 19 and 20:**

```
for (i in 0..20) {
    if (i % 3 == 2) {
        println(i + ", ");
    }
}
```